# How to increment the field in table using php based on other field?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three fields in the table as follows:

**| event_id | email | count |**

Now, I have to increment the values in the **count** field whenever **event_id** is found same. The increment has to be done based on the previous count value at the same **event_id**.

```
`$sql=$con->query("INSERT INTO usersregisteredevents (event_id,email) VALUES ('$event_id','$email')");`
```

**Please help with this.**

Comment: So if two rows have same event_id, do they have both same count = 2 or one has count = 1 and the other count = 2 ?

Comment: @PHPnoob one has count=1 and other count=2;

Comment: Consider not storing derived data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select count for the current event_id : `SELECT COUNT(count) FROM usersregisteredevents WHERE event_id = "$event_id")`
2. Do your insert with the value returned above as "count" value : `INSERT INTO usersregisteredevents (event_id, email, count) VALUES ('$event_id', '$email', $count)`

**Edit :**

If you want to start the counter at 1, just write `SELECT COUNT(count) + 1 FROM [...]`